# I get SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: unresolved element 'ref' attribute when i try to create the SoapClient in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have to use WSDL and SOAP to interact with a certain system, but when i load the wsdl file with the new SoapClient php class i get an error
`SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: unresolved element 'ref' attribute 'http://get_xxxx_response.xxx.xx.xxxx.xxxx.com:HEADER'`

(the xxxx i have put because i don't know if i can post the actual values)

the
`http://get_xxxx_response.xxx.xx.xxxx.xxxx.com`
is used as a xmlns and targetNamespace the xsd file like so

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://get_xxxx_response.xxx.xx.xxxx.xxxx.com"
    targetNamespace="http://get_xxxx_response.xxx.xx.xxxx.xxxx.com">
.
.
.
```

and again the wsdl file

```
<wsdl:definitions name="SERVICE_NAME"
.
.
.
xmlns:SERVICE_ACTION_NAME="http://get_xxxx_response.xxx.xx.xxxx.xxxx.com"   
.
.
.
```

The php i am using is

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$context =[
    'local_cert'    => 'xxxx',
    'passphrase'    => 'xxxx',
    'trace'=>true
];
$path='PATH_TO_THEWSDL';
try {
$soapclient = new SoapClient($path, $context);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I have looked as much as i can on the web, but nothing cam up a possible solution.
When i use the same wsdl with the SOAP UI, it seems to work. Maybse is some php soap client setting i am missing or smth along those lines. The php version is 8.2.10.
i will be very grateful if someone could at least point me in the direction on where to look for a solution

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research and trial and error i found out that if i replace the xs:include in the xsd files with xs:import, the wsdl is parsed correctly. I got this from an answer from 2011 from here

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44686